# Update gradle version from command line using Android command line tools

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have installed command-line tools (commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip) of Android Studio, and I want to update the gradle version to 6.2.

Any idea how I can do that?

In the UI I could just go to File -> Project structure.

Do I need the UI to do this?

tried to run: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.2 --distribution-type=all`

```
bash-4.2$ ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.2 --distribution-type=all

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myapp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.github.triplet.play', version: '2.7.5']
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.github.triplet.gradle.common.validation.RuntimeValidationPlugin']
   > Gradle Play Publisher's minimum Gradle version is at least Gradle 6.2 and yours
     is Gradle 5.6.4. Find the latest version at
     https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/latest, then run
     $ ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=$LATEST --distribution-type=ALL

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Gradle wrapper, you can simply run:

```sh
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.2
```

If you want to use a different distribution type than `bin` (default), you can add the `distribution-type` argument:

```sh
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.2 --distribution-type=all
```

Comment: Running this command showing the same error (added to the question)

Comment: @TheUnreal it happens because that plugin (`com.github.triplet.play`) fails during the configuration phase. Just comment the references to that plugin, run the command to update the wrapper that I wrote and uncomment the references to that plugin again.